# Xcode not obeying device orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, orientation

I have set the Device Orientation to have only 'Portrait' checked in Xcode.
However when I run my app in the simulator, it rotates in all orientations.

[My Xcode setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcS6h.png)

[Showing correctly in Portrait (intended) and Landscape (not intended)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w1PG.png)

Anyone faced same issue before?
Thanks

Comment: Check the _Supported interface orientations_ values in your `info.plist`

Comment: i have already included the following in my `info.plist`

 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
 </array>

Comment: I'm having the same issue. `info.plist` is good as well, any luck?

Comment: same issue. anyone found reason?

Comment: same issue here! this is a bug with Xcode and/or swiftUI. We would expect much more than this rubbish from Apple!!

Answer (score 49):

In my case (Xcode 13.1)，It works perfectly for me:

Follow steps:

1. choose your target;
2. select `Build Settings`;
3. select `All` and `Combined` options;
4. search `orientation` keywords
5. notice `Supported interface Orientations(iPhone)`, click the value of it on the right;
6. delete the orientations you don't want.

[image]

Comment: This works well.
I tried to disable it on "General" tab by using deselection but it was not working and they were remained on Build Settings. In Build Settings, I removed them and it worked well.
Thank you.

Comment: This works like a charm. No need to add to the Info.plist and no need to override in code. Thanks for this @zephyr

Comment: This works! Xcode 13.3.1 was not putting any entries into info.plist for Supported Interface Orientations when creating a new project. And even when I added them manually, Xcode would ignore them. @zephyr your answer is a life saver.

Answer (score 22):

The "General"->"Deployment Info" UI in Xcode can be deceiving. Check these two keys in your `info.plist`:

`UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`

and

`UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad`

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue and mine only shows `Portrait(bottom home button)`

Comment: i set both `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`, still not working.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: This helped me out, but I also wanted to add that in Xcode 13.0, SwiftUI projects don't autogenerate info.plist files for some reason. So if you go to the info tab after selecting your project's targets, you'll be able to edit the array and make it work.

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem (in physical devices). on iPhone it works fine but on iPad it does not work. The solution was to adjust the option of "devices" for both, in this case "landscape right".  [image: Landscape Right checkbox checked under Device Orientation below Deployment Info]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and costed my entire day onto it, i resolved by doing this:
override the AppDelegate method

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        

        if self.allowOrentitaionRotation {
            return .allButUpsideDown;
        }
        return .portrait;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Xcode 14 fixed the bug, now it is kind to config device orientation on iPhone and iPad:
[image]