# why Xcode 13 ignores devices orientation settings at all costs?

Tags: ios, xcode

Similar question here and not a single working answer:

[Xcode not obeying device orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279651/xcode-not-obeying-device-orientation)

it doesn't matter how I change the settings in Xcode 13 but when I run my app, it completely ignores the device orientation  settings.

I just want my app to be in portrait but it looks like I can go landscape (left/right) and any other orientations!

This is my settings:

**info.plist file:**

[image]

**Manual settings under the deployment:**

[image]

anyones got a solution for this as this is a very annoying bug in Xcode!

Answer (score 11):

Check

```
Targets > Build Settings > Info.Plist Values
```

Only these values have real effect, and they may be different from all other Xcode project settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 'Device Orientation' checkboxes seem to be broken in Xcode 13. They don't modify the info.plist entries at all. Maybe this has to do with the new info.plist slim template that Apple introduced at WWDC 2021.

Manually adding `Supported device orientation (iPhone)` seems to do the trick. However, it will not be reflected in Xcode Deployment Info's checkboxes.

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but it solves the problem and the Device orientation checkboxes work again. It looks like an Xcode bug. What you need to do - just delete `Supported interface orientations (iPhone)` in `Info.plist` and select the necessary checkboxes in `General`

XCode screenshot:

[image: XCode screenshot]